# Why is my for-loop breaking after the if-statement returns false?

Tags: c++, list, c++20

This is the search method of a linked list class I created. The for-loop "Find Nodes With Kind" is breaking the first time the if-statement is false. I've included the entire method, and the relevant constants, enum, struct, and variable outside of the method. I already tried adding braces and switching to a while-loop, same results. I've tested it in CLion and OnlineGDB.com.

There is no error. If `KIND` is the same kind of `Bead` (e.g. `copper`) as the one in position 0 it returns the pointer containing position 0, and every position directly following it that also contains that same bead kind, but does not contain the positions holding that bead kind after the first position which is not that bead kind. If a kind other than the one in the 0 position (e.g. 0 holds `silver` and searching for `copper`) then `nullptr` is returned.

```
/* list.h */

/* ...blah, blah, blah... */

// Enumerated Data Types
    // Bead Types
enum Bead: unsigned char{copper, silver, gold};

// Global Constants
const unsigned char X0 = 0, X1 = 1;

/* ...Other Stuff... */

class List
{
    /* ...irrelevant stuff...*/

    // Structures/Classes
    struct Node         // List's Node structure.
    {
        // Fields
        Bead   kind;        // Holds the kind of bead.
        Node * next;        // Points to the next Node.
        /* ...Other Stuff... */
    };

    // Fields
    Node * head;
    /* ...Other Stuff... */
public:
    /* ...Other Stuff... */

    // Methods
    size_t length() const;  // Length Retriever
    /* ...Other Stuff... */
};
/* ...Other Stuff... */

/* list.cpp */

/* ...blah, blah, blah... */

// Search Method
size_t * List::search(const Bead & KIND)
{
    // Method Variables/Constants
    List::Node   * node    = head;      // Pointer to move through the list.
    const size_t   L        {length()}, // Size of list.
                   LP1      {L + X1};   // List + 1 For Length
          size_t   position[LP1],       // Holds Positions Found
                   newSize = X1,        // Size of returned array.
                 * returned;            // Returned array.

    // Error Check
    if(!head) return nullptr;           // Return nullptr if empty.

    // Find Nodes With Kind
    for(size_t i = X0; i < L; ++i)      // Until end is reached:
        if(node->kind == KIND)          // If kind found:
        {                               // Add position to position[].
            position[newSize++] = i;    // Update newSize.
            node = node->next;          // Move to the next Node.
        }

    // When finished; set position[0] to newSize.
    position[X0] = newSize;

    // Return what was found; if anything.
    if(newSize > X1)
    {
        returned = new size_t[newSize];         // Create correctly sized array,
        for(size_t i = X0; i < newSize; ++i)        // and copy data over.
            *(returned + i) = position[i];
        return returned;                        // Then return it.
    }

    // Return nullptr if nothing was found:
    return nullptr;
}
/* ...Other Stuff... */
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. It's just stopping.

Comment: It would help if you created a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates your problem.

Comment: How does 'node' get updated if the if statement evaluates to false?

Comment: @NeilButterworth An array cannot be returned from a function in C++, the only option is a pointer. Also lining things up in columns makes it far easier to read, I couldn't guess what your problem is with it.

Comment: Do you think `position[newSize++] = i` is causing a heap overflow? I mean can you troubleshoot the values of `newSize` and whether it's over flowing your array and corrupting your heap, and, possibly corrupting `i` ?

Comment: My eyes glazed over after the fifth time I encountered "blah blah blah...irrelevant stuff...other stuff...", and I still hadn't reached the part of the code that was apparently related to anything you were doing. You seem to have some awareness of the notion of a _minimal_ reproducible example, but this code has some way to go before it reaches it.

Comment: @Tony  You're absolutely right, I overlooked an ultra basic programming error. I must be too burned out. Thank you, it works perfectly now.

Comment: you can return a List if you have written the class properly,. and your ideas of readability differ from mine

Comment: @NeilButterworth The list is for an enum, not a list of size_t positions within the list. I'd have to create a second list class for that, when I can much more easily just send a pointer. That would have been obvious if you understood the concept of a search method.

Comment: then return a vector of size_t, though i think your design is  wrong. in general, never return a pointer allocated by new or malloc or similar from a function

Comment: A comment formatted like `/* ...[X]... */` draws one's attention to `[X]`. The goal of omitting unnecessary code is to allow one's attention to drift *away* from the omission. To achieve this goal, drop the emphasis, as in `/*[X]*/` or `// [X]`. Or drop the comment altogether in the cases where a placeholder comment adds nothing to the example (such as the "blah"s).

Comment: That loop only advances `node = node->next` if `node->kind == KIND`. If the first node doesn't match - that is, `head->kind != KIND` - that loop will just check `head->kind` over and over and not ever look at any other node.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I had with your code are:

- why do the arrays not start at index 0?
- why bother with creating a temporary array, just populate the final array
- populating the resultant array is weird, why use `*(returned + i) = ...` and not `returned[i] = ...`

I had a tinker with your code and this is what I came up with. It is not exactly the same as your code, since I didn't understand certain aspects of your code, but, I think you should be able to use it as a template to shorten your code:

```cpp
size_t * List::search(const Bead & KIND)
{
    size_t total = 0;
    for (List::Node* node = head; node; node = node->next)
    {
        if (node->kind == KIND)
            total++;
    }
    if (!total)
        return nullptr;
    size_t* result = new size_t[total];
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t resultIndex = 0;
    for (List::Node* node = head, index = 0; node; node = node->next, index++)
    {
        if (node->kind == KIND)
            result[resultIndex++] = index;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that this API assumes that the caller will take care of checking the resultant pointer and take care of deleting it. This is not a good design since, is (1) API should be responsible for deleting whatever it creates, (2) push the responsibility for allocating and deallocating the array back to the caller.